# Using one xml element inside another

Tags: xml

I'm beginner in xml.
I'm just wondering:

```
<element1 id='foo'>
  <someField>bar</someField>
</element1>
<element2>
  <element1 id='foo'></element1> //not sure here
  <someField2>baz</someField2>
</element2>
```

how to use this element there. Ofc its bigger collection, its just to demonstrate the problem.
Is there any solution without using external tools?

Comment: I could not find a good Stack Overflow answer, so I will refer you to this link. The third listing, scroll down a bit, might help you. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipvocab/index.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on "using"? You can add any XML element at any position (assuming the defined schema allows it), so what is the problem with the XML code you have or what do you want to do exactly? Please [edit] your question with the new information, maybe even post a more detailed example of your XML code.